# PHP How to properly merge arrays for following json structure

Tags: php, arrays, json

So i tried a lot of possible codes out but i can't seem to find a proper solution.

First let's start with the the wished array (i will show it in a json format as it's easier to read)

```json
{
    "transaction": {
        "input": [
            {
                "address": "a",
                "value": 4294967295
            },
            {
                "address": "b",
                "value": 51515
            }
        ],
        "output": [
            {
                "address": "aa",
                "value": 551
            },
            {
                "address": "bb",
                "value": 66564
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using 2 foreach loops to get data that i wanna put in `inputs` & `outputs`

Here's the code im using:

```php
//Get Output Addresses & Value
$tmp_array = array();
foreach($json['result']['vout'] as $a)
{
    $value = $a['value'];
    $address = $a['scriptPubKey']['addresses'][0];
    
    $tmp_array = array('wallet' => $address, 'value' => $value);
    $input = array_merge($input, $tmp_array);


};

$input = array('inputs' => $tmp_array);
$input = json_encode($input);
print_r($input);
```

That's the code for me getting the data and trying to put it into the array. Now i have a problem, it only adds data from the last iteration of the loop. I'm trying to get a code that gets it in a strucuture like above. **Whatever solution gets sent, it should be applicable so i can paste the same code in the other loop that is for the outputs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the `$input` variable after the loop with the value of `$tmp_array` which will be the value from the last iteration, as you described. To fix this you should initialize the `$input` array as empty array at the beginning and merge that with the new data:

```php
//Get Output Addresses & Value
$inputs = array();
foreach($json['result']['vout'] as $a)
{
    $value = $a['value'];
    $address = $a['scriptPubKey']['addresses'][0];
    
    $tmp_array = array('wallet' => $address, 'value' => $value);
    $inputs[] = $tmp_array; // push to array
};

$input = json_encode(array('inputs' => $inputs));
print_r($input);
```

Comment: This gives out an empty array: `{"inputs":[]}`

Comment: Of course! I made a mistake, will edit it.

Comment: @SamUncle no problem! If this solved your problem, could you please mark the answer as such? Thanks.